# Convert Microsoft Word Document to array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a table (N x M) in Microsoft Word Document (.docs). How can I read this table in C# and enter all values in 2-dim array (N x M)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use third party library or the dedicated [Microsoft OpenXML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) to do this. [Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1043875/Create-Word-table-using-OpenXML-and-Csharp-Without) some documentation about how word tables works using the OpenXML SDK.

Also, as mentionned, docx are packed zip with xml files inside them, you can go the brute way or using COM Interop.

Answer (score 1):

.docx file is a zip archive with some service files insde. You can programmaticaly unpack file, containing your data and read it as standart xml-file.

If you want to use COM, you should:

1. Create COM object
2. Open required .docx
3. Navigate throught doc to table
4. Read it cell by cell